# How to generate a ddl creation script with a modern Spring Boot + Data JPA and Hibernate setup?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Currently, I'm using the default `@SpringBootApplication` annotation with the following properties in `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname
spring.datasource.username=X
spring.datasource.password=X
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=my.package.CustomNamingStrategy
```

Since JPA 2.1, I should be able to use the `javax.persistence.schema-generation.*` properties, but setting them in my application.properties seems to have no effect.

I've seen examples [like this](https://gist.github.com/jbrackett/8899299) that wire up a whole bunch of extra beans, but they aren't using Mysql. And in any case, doing it like that requires me to configure many options that spring is taking care of for me now.

My goals are to:

- Generate a schema creation sql script in the MYSQL dialect
- without a database connection being required
- Output the script in the build directory
- Also generating hibernate envers tables would be a huge plus.

I do not want to:

- Create/drop schemas on a live database

Lib versions:

```
   hibernate          : 4.3.11.FINAL
   spring framework   : 4.2.5.RELEASE
   spring-boot        : 1.3.3.RELEASE
   spring-data-jpa    : 1.10.1.RELEASE   // for  querydsl 4 support
   spring-data-commons: 1.12.1.RELEASE   // for  querydsl 4 support
```

(Using gradle, not maven)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Ah, right after I posted this question a section of the spring data docs caught my eye:

> [73.5 Configure JPA properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-jpa-properties)  In addition all properties in
>   spring.jpa.properties.* are passed through as normal JPA properties
>   (with the prefix stripped) when the local EntityManagerFactory is
>   created.

So, to answer my own question: prefix the javax.persistence properties with spring.jpa.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source=metadata
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=create
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=create.sql
```

After doing this, the schema file was generated automatically in the project root.

Comment: Ammended the answer, essentially after adding that config, the file was created automatically in the generated sources dir.

Comment: I saw that the file is generated at runtime. Is there a way to generate it 'offline'?

Comment: is there a way to add ; after each of the ddl commands? is it possible for this to run without create-drop/create ddl ? is it possible to run without running the whole application ?

Comment: @MichailMichailidis For running it without running the whole app I would recommend checkout out flyway to manage your schema: https://flywaydb.org/

Comment: What I'd like to do is generate the DDL to a text file, to make it easier to set up the boilerplate work for a Flyway migration, not to execute it automatically...

Comment: When will it be generated ?

Comment: Thank you it works, this itself is not enough, please refer this answer as well, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48423854/missing-semicolons-at-line-end-of-jpa-generated-sql-script

Comment: Is there any way to filter the scope? Something like: "generate  just from entities from package X"

Comment: I am not sure, that first row is needed. If I want to generate only the script the first declaration is obsolete.

Comment: What if I want to get "update.sql" for existing database instead of create DDLs to empty database?

Comment: It appends instead of replace the file. Can this be changed?

Comment: Nowadays, Aug 2023, it is more likely that you are using the Jakarta Persistence, so the property names would begin with `spring.jpa.properties.jakarta.persistence.` as opposed to `spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.`

Comment: Hi @IsmailYavuz, I am currently trying to get an "update.sql" for an exising database just like you. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Not really @Eloi however liquibase have some SQL generating options. You may have an empty/local database for starting point (it can be total empty or hibernate auto-ddl created as you wish) and then ask liquibase for generating an update query file for 2 databases, it migrates one of them to the other (as per your parameters). In all cases you have to check the resulting SQL carefully by your eyes. For example a table rename may cause drop/create and loss of all data.

Answer (score 19):

This is yml specific configuration for making spring boot generate ddl creation script in root folder:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      javax:
        persistence:
          schema-generation:
            create-source: metadata
            scripts:
              action: create
              create-target: create.sql
```

Comment: Please provide some info to your answer.

Comment: Here is the same for *.properties file spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source=metadata
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=create
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=create.sql

Comment: It appends instead of replace the file. Can this be changed?

Answer (score 6):

The following code will allow you to generate the DDL for all discovered entities in a stand-alone fashion (independently from Spring Boot). This allows you to generate the schema without having to start the main application.

It uses the following dependencies:

- `org.hibernate:hibernate-core`
- `org.reflections:reflections`

```
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;
import org.hibernate.tool.schema.TargetType;
import org.reflections.Reflections;
import org.reflections.util.ConfigurationBuilder;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class SchemaGenerator {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        new SchemaGenerator().generateSchema();
    }

    private void generateSchema() {
        var serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySetting("hibernate.dialect", "<fully qualifified dialect class name>")
                .build();
        var entities = scanForEntities("<package1>", "<package2>");
        MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry);
        entities.forEach(metadataSources::addAnnotatedClass);
        Metadata metadata = metadataSources.buildMetadata();
        SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport();
        schemaExport.setFormat(true);
        schemaExport.setOutputFile("<output file name>");
        schemaExport.createOnly(EnumSet.of(TargetType.SCRIPT), metadata);
    }

    private Set<Class<?>> scanForEntities(String... packages) {
        var reflections = new Reflections(
                new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .forPackages(packages)
        );
       return reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating your `jpa properties` will generate the scripts for you.

```
            <prop key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action">drop-and-create</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target">./create_mssql.sql</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target">./drop_mssql.sql</prop>
```

This will generate the scripts in the given location. There are other properties as well which can be used on various use-cases, please refer [here](https://thoughts-on-java.org/standardized-schema-generation-data-loading-jpa-2-1/)

The whole configuration will look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="my-persistence-unit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <description>Forge Persistence Unit</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>

      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="META-INF/data.sql"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: you are asking why it is not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55275380/not-able-to-generate-ddl-schema-for-my-spring-entites-in-my-spring-application/55286744#55286744 and posting same answer?

Comment: I got the answer, it was property missed out

Comment: Can you put there more structured code example? I put your example into `jpaProperties` section under `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` in `aplicationContext.xml`, but it does nothing.

Comment: I have added the whole config file.