# Spring data JPA: how to enable cascading delete without a reference to the child in the parent?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Maybe this is an overly simple question, but I am getting an exception when I try to delete a user entity.

The user entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User 
{
    @Transient
    private static final int SALT_LENGTH = 32;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    @Column(unique = true, length = 254)
    @NotNull
    private String email;

    // BCrypt outputs 60 character results.
    @Column(length = 60)
    private String hashedPassword;

    @NotNull
    private String salt;

    private boolean enabled;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private Date createdDate;
```

And I have an entity class which references a user with a foreign key. What I want to happen is that when the user is deleted, any `PasswordResetToken` objects that reference the user are also deleted. How can I do this?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "password_reset_tokens")
public class PasswordResetToken 
{
    private static final int EXPIRATION_TIME = 1; // In minutes

    private static final int RESET_CODE_LENGTH = 10;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String token;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "userId")
    private User user;

    private Date expirationDate;
```

The exception I am getting boils down to `` Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`heroku_bc5bfe73a752182`.`password_reset_tokens`, CONSTRAINT `FKk3ndxg5xp6v7wd4gjyusp15gq` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) ``

I'd like to avoid adding a reference to `PasswordResetToken` in the parent entity, becaue `User` shouldn't need to know anything about `PasswordResetToken`.

Comment: suppose you take a look at this [post](https://vladmihalcea.com/2015/03/05/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/) and it explains more about your issue and solution.

Comment: suppose you have to add `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)`

Comment: To the user entity? Or the PasswordResetToken entity? I didn't really want to add any reference to the child in the User entity, since the user entity shouldn't need to know about the existence of the reset token.

Comment: to `PasswordResetToken`

Comment: I get `Unknown MappedBy` error. Why?

Comment: If you do not want to update the JPA model, you will need to cascade the delete on the database side as `ALTER TABLE password_reset_tokens DROP CONSTRAINT FKk3ndxg5xp6v7wd4gjyusp15gq;`, followed by `ALTER TABLE password_reset_tokens ADD CONSTRAINT FKk3ndxg5xp6v7wd4gjyusp15gq FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES users(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible on JPA level without creating a bidirectional relation. You need to specify cascade type in `User` class. `User` should be owner of the relation and it should provide the information on how to deal with related `PasswordResetToken`.

But if you cannot have a bidirectional relation I would recommend you to setup relation directly in schema generation SQL script.

If you create your schema via SQL script and not via JPA autogeneration (I believe all serious projects must follow this pattern) you can add `ON DELETE CASCADE` constraint there.

It will look somehow like this:

```
CREATE TABLE password_reset_tokens (
  -- columns declaration here
  user_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_PASSWORD_RESET_TOKEN_USER_ID
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Here is [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-use-a-higher-level-database-migration-tool) on how to use DB migration tools with spring boot. And here is [the information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36966419/2065796) on how to generate schema script from hibernate (that will simplify the process of writing your own script).

Comment: I agree you need it in the DDL - then future developers are left trying to decipher how the child record has disappeared before checking the DDL

Answer (score 5):

Parent Entity:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private PasswordResetToken passwordResetToken;
```

Child Entity:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "PasswordResetToken", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private User user;
```

If you want the Password entity to be hidden from the client, you can write a custom responses and hide it. Or if you want to ignore it by using `@JsonIgnore`

If you don't want the reference in the Parent Entity (User), then you have to override the default method `Delete()` and write your logic to find and delete the *PasswordResetToken* first and then the *User*.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Entity listener and Callback method](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html) `@PreRemove` to delete an associated 'Token' before the 'User'.

```
@EntityListeners(UserListener.class)
@Entity
public class User {

    private String name;
}

@Component
public class UserListener {

    private static TokenRepository tokenRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setTokenRepository(TokenRepository tokenRepository) {
        PersonListener.tokenRepository = tokenRepository;
    }

    @PreRemove
    void preRemove(User user) {
        tokenRepository.deleteByUser(user);
    }
}
```

where `deleteByPerson` is very simple method of your 'Token' repository:

```
public interface TokenRepository extends JpaRepository<Token, Long> {
    void deleteByUser(User user);
}
```

Pay attention on static declaration of `tokenRepository` - without this Spring could not inject `TokenRepository` because, as I can understand, `UserListener` is instantiated by Hybernate (see additional info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12241344/5380322)).

Also as we can read in the [manual](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html#d0e3013),

> a callback method must not invoke EntityManager or Query methods!

But in my simple test all works OK.

Working [example](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/tree/master/src/main/java/restsdemo/example7) and [test](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/blob/master/src/test/java/restsdemo/example7/PersonListenerTest.java).