# using JPA CRUD to cascade delete parent explicitly without using annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Right now, if I want to delete a Parent entry from database, I would use cascade annotation in the Parent class, so that a deletion of Parent would also delete any children tied to it.  Like this:

```
@Entity
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<Child> children;
}

@Entity
public class Child implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Parent parent;  
}
```

The actual deletion would be like this:

```
this.parentRepository.delete(parentID);
```

However, if I want to explicitly choose whether to cascade delete or to simple delete, how would I do that?

I don't think I can choose to turn off the cascade annotation in code manually, so is there a way to cascade delete without using annotation?

Comment: Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44338431).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not delete parent if child has relation on parent. It's not good way. In db child should not have `notNull` restriction on parent

But you really want control cascade deletion, I would recommend use `@EntityListeners`:

```
@EntityListeners({ParentJpaCallbacksListener.class})
@Entity
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Child> children;
}
```

where

```
@Component
public class ParentJpaCallbacksListener {
    @Autoware ChildRepository childRepository;

    @PreRemove
    // or @PostRemove
    void preRemove(Parent parent) {
        // your cascade deletion logic 
        // for example use childRepository to delete some children
    }

}
```

In this way you should not have `cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE`.