# Missing semicolons at line-end of JPA-generated sql script

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa

I am using JPA to generate a script for creating database tables based on my entities:

```
javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=create
javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=db_setup.sql
```

The file is generated with the correct tables, however the statements do not end with a semicolon, for example:

```
create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint)
insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
```

I assume this is valid in standard SQL? However, it is not valid in MySQL. Is there a way to tell JPA to add the semicolons to the end of the line? Or what else could be the reason that it is missing?

Comment: you need to add semicolon, don't assume

Comment: better still, raise a bug on your JPA provider for generating something that cannot be executed directly

Comment: I couldn't image that hibernate doesn't add semicolons when creating the sql statements, that's why I was asking. But it seem you are correct, this is already tracked here: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10278

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since Hibernate 5.1.0, the line delimiter for the generated SQL can be defined by setting the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.delimiter` property, e.g.

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.delimiter=";"
```

The default is no delimiter.

See also comments on [this ticket](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10278).