# Generate CREATE script for Spring Boot, Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, command-line-interface

I'm looking to generate an SQL script that creates the tables I need in the database based on the my configuration setup in Spring Boot.

I've got this `application-prod.yml` config

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@removed:1521:XE
    username: user
    password: pass
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
      naming:
        physical-strategy: CustomPhysicalNamingStrategyImpl
    properties:
      hibernate:
        default_schema: myschema
```

I used to just do `ddl-auto: create-drop`, but that is no longer an option.

In ASP.NET Core I'm used to doing it via the [command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-migrations-script). Like so:

> `> dotnet ef --output create.sql`

And I'm done.

But I can't find an equivalent way for Spring Boot and Hibernate.

Right now it seems like I have to edit my config run the app, export the database schema via Oracle SQL Developer, then revert the config. Hope I don't forget something.

Surely this can't be the case...

Comment: `that is no longer an option` You might want to explain why (such as a change from Spring Boot 1.5 to 2.0, or something else).

Comment: The db user dones't have create permissions

Comment: Try to use liquibase: https://medium.com/@harittweets/evolving-your-database-using-spring-boot-and-liquibase-844fcd7931da

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a ddl creation script with a modern Spring Boot + Data JPA and Hibernate setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966337/how-to-generate-a-ddl-creation-script-with-a-modern-spring-boot-data-jpa-and-h)