# Spring JPA properties does not generate the database

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Good night everyone, I am trying to generate the create.sql file so that I can easily create my database in postresSQL with the commands that the create.sql file will generate from query but the create.sql file is not generated myself using the code below could someone help me to solve this problem?

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source=metadata
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=create
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=create.sql
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.delimiter=;

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dsdeliver
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=abrantes1

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Comment: Yikes, please do not use all capital letters.  It feels like shouting and is rude.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36966419/924036