# How to generate a DDL script from Hibernate with Spring Boot 3 (Jakarta version)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

The answer to [How to generate a ddl creation script with a modern Spring Boot + Data JPA and Hibernate setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966337/how-to-generate-a-ddl-creation-script-with-a-modern-spring-boot-data-jpa-and-h) shows that it can be done with Spring Boot 2 by adding these properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source=metadata
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=create
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=create.sql
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.delimiter=;
```

This is something I have done in the past as well. For Spring Boot 3, I tried with these (accounting for the change from `javax` to `jakarta`):

```
spring.jpa.properties.jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.create-source=metadata
spring.jpa.properties.jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=create
spring.jpa.properties.jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=create.sql
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.delimiter=;
```

But the `create.sql` is not generated. Have the properties changed completely? How to do it now with Hibernate 6?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. It works like this, I was just looking at the wrong place for the generated file. Using that `jakarta` replacement works.